# Redmine issue content is filtered by post processing

Tags: redmine

We are currently in the process of migrating from a self-written issue tracking system to Redmine. To support the old format best, we added the format of our old system as a Text formatting via a plugin. We've wrote a rake task that migrates the data from the old system 1:1 to the new system (aka not changing format to Textile).

After migrating, taking a look at the issues, the plugin seems to work well. HTML is displayed almost exactly as it looked in the previous system.

However, there has to be a post processing stage where certain functionality is inserted still, for instance the formatting of numbers after hashes (`#\d+`) as links to issues. We know that our Text formatting plugin doesn't do that.

What bothers us is that this post processing stage seems to remove certain HTML elements. For instance, tables disappear completely. Neither `<table>` nor `<td>` nor `<tr>` can be found in the output that Redmine displays, although our parser definitely output a table.

We've played around with the ALLOWED_TAGS functionality, but even allowing the mentioned HTML tags doesn't change the removal of the tags.

3 questions for this:

- Is this configurable somewhere?
- Where can we find the source of this post processing stage?
- Is there a documentation mentioning this anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like I get it.

Your output is parsed by internal stuff of Redmine.
First stand is in: `lib/wiki_formatting/textile/formatter.rb`
 formatting rules are defined here as:

```
RULES = [:textile, :block_markdown_rule, :inline_auto_link, :inline_auto_mailto]
```

Actually this is defined in settings.yml:

```
text_formatting:
  default: textile
```

and now the last place. Method which wrap near every text displayed in Redmine. File: `application_controller.rb`
method `def textilizable`

line `text = Redmine::WikiFormatting.to_html(Setting.text_formatting, text, :object => obj, :attribute => attr)`

You can tweak any place to get rid of forced formatting. If you want totally drop Redmine "magic", just modify last one. If not - modify RULES.

Comment: Well, the plugin is kinda private, but it's only using parts of wikimedia formatting with some other tag types and outputs HTML, so there's nothing special about it.

Comment: There might have been a misunderstanding. The issues I referred to have never been saved using the new Redmine system. We've just converted them from the old system and are now trying to get the formatting right in the new system. That is where we see that tables are missing, and #123 like texts are replaced by links to issues. What we postulate exists is a post processing after the configured Text formatting plugin is done with an issue, and before it is displayed in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. One last question: This mechanism is run even if "Textile" is not used as text formatting (aka, not configured in settings)?

Comment: If you just delete default section it will fail on config read. If make it empty, it will failback to NullFormatter module defined in wiki_formatting.rb